# GWT elements are not visible

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, gxt

I have already asked such a question here but haven't got a reply which could work out. It is really important for me to resolve the problem. So, I try to develop an app using ExtGWT 2.3.0 / GWT 2.5.1 but faced the problem that widgets (both GWT and GXT) are not visible in browsers. I've been trying to solve this issue more than week but unfortunatelly I've failed. The stuff I have alredy tried:

- using different libraries of GWT/GXT (using ExtGXT 3.x doesn't settle a problem);
- creating project using Maven web-app / gxt3+ archetypes;
- deploying project on Tomacat / lunching under GWT;
- using different styles in GWT-module (like `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>`);
- rewriting .css-file;
- compiling project by Maven / GWT compiler;
- cleaning up cache files in all relevant temp directories (as Windows' as well as Intellij IDEA's);
- making Maven's `clean install`;
- using different browsers of different versions (IE 8 and 11, Chrome, FF 24 and 36);
- trying to lunch app in browsers with / without GWT developer plugin;
- browsing internet to find solution (especially stackoverflow);

Maybe I left out smth but the list of actions is pretty much big.
By the way I logged actions and there were no any errors or exeptions thrown. If I declare border settings for the widgets in .css their borders become visible that testifies that widgets are on page. So, if anyone has experienced such a problem or just could suggest something please let me know. Frankly it is very important for me. Please take a look at screenshots of the folder structure / setting of the project. Thank you in advance.

**EntryPoint - class**

```
public class ProjectEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Viewport viewport = new Viewport();
        final BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();

        BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.NORTH, 20);
        northData.setSplit(false);
        northData.setCollapsible(false);

        BorderLayoutData centerData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.CENTER);
        centerData.setCollapsible(false);

        BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.WEST, 200, 150, 300);
        westData.setCollapsible(true);
        westData.setSplit(true);

        ContentPanel mainPanel = new ContentPanel();
        mainPanel.setStyleName("mainPanel");
        ContentPanel navPanel = new ContentPanel();
        mainPanel.setStyleName("navPanel");

        HTML headerHTML = new HTML();
        headerHTML.setHTML("<h1>RSS Reader</h1>");

        viewport.add(mainPanel, centerData);
        viewport.add(navPanel, westData);
        viewport.add(headerHTML, northData);
        viewport.setLayout(borderLayout);
        viewport.layout();
        RootPanel.get().add(viewport);
    } 
}
```

**module**

```
<module rename-to='Project'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
  <inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT' />
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <entry-point class='GXT3App.client.ProjectEntryPoint' />
  <source path='client' />
  <source path='shared' />
  <add-linker name="xsiframe" />
</module>
```

**.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="gxt-all.css">
    <title>Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Project/Project.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**.css**

```
.mainPanel {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.navPanel {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image: folder structure]
[image: GWT config]
[image: WAR structure]
[image: Result on web-page]

Comment: Don't post the same question twice to "get attention". Edit the old one and add a bounty to get more eyes on it. Don't spam the site with duplicate questions in the future.

Comment: I deleted old question and renewed one by describing the problem and stuff I did to solve it. It is not to attract attention but to have all information regarding the issue in one place. I think it is more clear and concisely.

Comment: did u try any other browser apart from IE?

Comment: Thanks, aime. This question is indeed well formed, I just didn't want some other question being abandoned. Now for the problem itself - the border is shown, so something works. I've always used a `BorderLayoutContainer` for such use cases, event the samples do that: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:borderlayout.  Can you try it instead of `BorderLayout`?

Comment: Thank you, but BorderLayoutContainer is only avaliable in GXT 3.x. I use GXT 2.3. I tried to change lib on 3.x but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that part. In that case the best I can recommend is going from a minimal working configuration and build from there. Try adding just the `HTML` widget to the `RootPanel`. Then add a `Viewport` and `HTML`. And lastly, lay it out with `BorderLayout`. I'd wager it's the `BorderLayout` that's the culprit, but I don't have a GXT 2.x at hand so I can't test it. Also, look at the browser's console for an exception you might have missed. BTW, you're adding the `navPanel` class to `mainPanel` :) No difference now, but it could lead to bugs later.

Comment: Igor, I tried to add just HTML and ContentPanel. Result - HTML header is visible but ContentPanel is not. Firefox console log shows a lot of errors (a part of them is following): [22:56:18.892] Error in parsing value for 'cursor'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://127.0.0.1:8888/Project/gwt/standard/standard.css:53  / [22:56:18.893] Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://127.0.0.1:8888/Project/gwt/standard/standard.css:160 / [22:56:18.959] Use of nsIDOMWindowInternal is deprecated. Use nsIDOMWindow instead. @ http://127.0.0.1:8888/Project.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997:347

Comment: More over when I opened standard.css in Notepad almost all the selectors are highlighted in red. If I understand it correctly there are some problems with .css which defines standard style for GWT-widgets. What to do with that?

Comment: Well then, it looks like a problem with styles. Is `gxt-all.css` available where it should be? Looking at the samples for GXT 2.3, you only need `<inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT' />`. At least *don't* inherit the standard theme of GWT, it could mess things up. Oh, and if you have to use GXT (and it's possible to choose at this point of your project) do make an effort and use 3.x. It's so much better than 2.3... That being said, it's not that great overall (I know, I've worked with it for 2 years and it blew in our faces in the end).

Comment: @Igor, thanks! You are right - the problem is in absence of `gxt-all.css`. Right now I'm developing at another work station where another GWT/GXT project is located and which works properly. I created new project under GWT/GXT and it had the same problem. I just added `gxt-all.css` from properly working project to classpath, override path to it in host-html and it worked out. All `ContentPannels`  are rendered and `BorderLaoutData` are layout elements properly. But there is a tiny issue - there are no tool buttons on `ContentPanels`.

Comment: I've been trying to use different approaches to make tools visible but haven't found solution yet. As for your suggestion regarding migration to GXT3.x - I joined a project which is built on GXT 2.3.1, so the only solution for me is to go into this version of GXT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with missing styles - please double check that `gxt-all.css` is available from where you reference it in your host page. Use your browser's developer tools to see if it's not throwing a `404`.

It seems that the missing resources are mentioned in **Step 1** in the `setup.txt` file that is bundled with GXT 2.3:

1. Create a Google Web Application Project project within Eclipse.

   **Copy the contents of the /resources folder in the download to a {foldername} location within your war folder.
   Substitute {foldername} with the name of the folder you've created for resources within your war folder.**
2. Add the following stylesheet to your host page.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{foldername}/css/gxt-all.css" />
   ```
3. If you are using Charts, add the following script to your host page.

4. Add the following entry to you projects module xml file.

   ```
   <inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
   ```
5. Eclipse Setup (should be similar for other development environments). These instructions assume you have a existing project and launch configuration.

   1. Add gxt.jar to the project.
   2. Add GXT jar to launch configuration.

Comment: I've written the solution that we reached in the comments above in the form of a proper answer, so that it'd be easier to find for other people having this problem.

Comment: I got that, thanks. I think I've found the root of all problems. In properly working project there is not only `gxt-all.css` but also a lot of images which represent such elements of widgets as tool buttons, scroll elements, etc. It turns out that in my case just presence of `gxt-all.css` is not enough. I have just one question - why all that stuff are not included in web-directory when the project is created. More over I've never seen any information that all that stuff (gxt-css, image - files) have to be involved in the project under GXT.

Comment: I've found the information regarding `resources` folder. Hope this clears things up (though I would expect, like you, that this step should be somehow automatic...).

Comment: thank you! Installation folder should be the first place to take a look at.) So the problem is solved but right now I faced almost the same problem at another workign station. I did all the stuff needed but Firefox shows a lot of errors in console like :`Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped.. ` or `Unknown property '-moz-opacity'.  Declaration dropped.. `. I validated `gxt-all.css` in CSS-validator and it shown the same errors also. I tried 3 different `gxt-all.css` from different gxt-libs but result was the same. What might it be?   It is really strange.

Comment: Well, this might be a different problem - please create a new question, if needed. If you have a working project in one place, and it's not working on another, it's hard to pin point the problem. Make sure all the files are copied over, the browser's cache is clean, etc. Is the version of Firefox the same, have you tried other browsers...

Comment: I copied folders from working project to the new one and it worked out. The problem appeared to be in incorrect .css.

Answer (score 0):

This surely can't be the answer, but you have a typo in your code :

```
    ContentPanel mainPanel = new ContentPanel();
    mainPanel.setStyleName("mainPanel");
    ContentPanel navPanel = new ContentPanel();
    mainPanel.setStyleName("navPanel");
```

where the last line (I think) should be

```
   navPanel.setStyleName("navPanel");
```

Comment: thank you but it will not work out. The solution of the problem I described in comments to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I wouldn't say that it is an elegant solution but it works.
As discussed above the problem was in absence of .css-file which defined selectors that described widgets' styles (**gxt-all.css**). When creating project be sure that the following folders with relevant files are presented in project's webapp-directory (in the case you use Maven's web-app-archetype):

- **chart**
- **css** (contains gxt-all.css and gxt-grey.css)
- **desktop**
- **flash**
- **images**
- **themes**

All that stuff you can find in GXT installation archive in the folder **resources**. To use it just put all that folders in your project and define path to **gxt-all.css** in your host-html. It works for GXT 2.x.